# Which "bra" came first?

Tags: etymology

Most people associate the word "bra" is an abbreviation of "brassiere".

But in science "bra" is a type of vector which is part of bra-ket notation. I think it sounds a little awkward. What's up with that?

Which one came first?

Comment: They are different domains. While there may be openings for juvenile humor,  no one will actually be confused as to the proper meaning within each domain.

Comment: It appears that both usages appeared in the 1930s. One has to learn to be grown-up about these at first jarring resemblances. Although Rolls-Royce renamed their 'Silver Mist' as 'Mist' means something else in German.

Comment: 1) Bra- by 1923, shortening of brassiere. (Etymonline) 2) Bra-ket -  Concatenation of the terms bra and ket, which were introduced in 1939 and in turn derive from the splitting of the English word bracket. (Wiktionary)

Comment: _Libra_ is from 1398. _Algebra_ is from 1400. _Abracadabra_ is from 1565. _Zebra_ is from 1597. _Umbra_ is from 1601. _Vertebra_ is from 1615.  _Cobra_ is from 1818.

Comment: Actually Bra is a town in the wine area of Piedmonte in Italy. I rather think that came first.

Comment: When I learned Swedish for a year at university, I found it strange that _bra_ is the word for _good_. It only gradually dawned on me that it corresponds to the Scots word _braw_.

Comment: Just wait until you get to junior astronomy. No matter the authorities' flailing attempts to change the pronunciation, Uranus will ever provoke humour -[compulsory Spitting Image sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHp9Cakv2Fg)

Comment: Another use of the word is in computer programming. Certain microprocessors, like the  [6502](http://www.6502.org/tutorials/65c02opcodes.html), PICs or the 68000 family, have a BRA instruction which will '**BR**anch **A**lways'. This makes sense as they also have instructions like BEQ for '**B**ranch if **EQ**ual' or BMI for '**B**ranch if **MI**nus'

Comment: Just wait until you have to write a paper with [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) and want to know how to format these vectors. Typing "latex bra" into google isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: And as Hot Licks reports in a comment to [a question about the countability of *toast*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/286972/70686): "And, yes, there was usually a snicker from the peanut gallery when "rubbers" was mentioned."

Comment: @pipe: fortunately, googling "latex ket" takes you straight [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214728/braket-notation-in-latex).

Comment: @David It's only called a "bra" if it's from Piedmonte, otherwise it's just a sparkling camisole.

Comment: @pipe: I've had similar issues searching for documentation on MFC's `CString` class.

Comment: Also, BRA is Brazil's IOC country code.  Which means that Brazil's female Olympic athletes wear sports bras with BRA prominently written on them, which looks a bit silly out of context, like having SHOE written on one's shoes.

Answer (score 40):

The *bra* from physics came from Dirac breaking the word *bracket* into *bra* + *ket*. He introduced these terms in 1939. [See Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bra-ket).

The clothing *bra* came from an abbreviation of the word *brassiere*, which the OED says first appeared in 1936. The other answer and the comments actually have instances of *bra* that appeared earlier, but these must have been quite rare if the OED couldn't find them.

So the fact that these words are identical may be a complete coincidence. Given the timing, it's also possible that it is a piece of juvenile humor on Dirac's part, but I suspect the clothing *bra* was generally still called a *brassiere* in 1939, and that Dirac didn't realize that there would be an unfortunate overlap of terminology.

Comment: From [Life](https://i.imgur.com/cqRJhRh.jpg) magazine June 7, 1937. I'm not quite sure what to make of it.

Comment: Based on what's known of Dirac, that sort of pun seems entirely out of character for him, and coincidence much more likely.

Comment: I have been told that Dirac was unaware of the other meaning, and considered it at best a mildly-humorous coincidence.

Comment: Related to G-string theory.

Comment: "these must have been quite rare if the OED couldn't find them": or they didn't look very hard.  _Life_ magazine isn't exactly very obscure.  Regardless, the word may have been rare in print without being rare in spoken language, especially denoting as it does one of a class of garments sometimes called "unmentionables."

Comment: @phoog: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wearing+a+bra%2Cwearing+a+brassiere&year_start=1900&year_end=1960&corpus=26&smoothing=1) also shows that *bra* was quite rare (at least in writing) until 1935 or so.  And I really don't see why "bra" should have been any more unmentionable than "brassiere", but I suppose it's possible.

Answer (score 18):

This answer is meant to supplement the others already given by providing more details on the sources and dates.

The answer to the original question, as others have already said, is that the *bra* as an abbreviation of *brassiere* came before Dirac's *bra*.

**Dirac's *bra***

Dirac's *bra* comes from breaking up<sup>1</sup> the word *bracket* into *bra* and *ket* (this is obvious but is also confirmed by the *OED*); see e.g. [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=nS0C9Loq5B0C&newbks=0&lpg=PA41&dq=bra%20ket%20bracket&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=bra%20ket%20bracket&f=false) for details.

<sup><sup>1</sup>And dropping the middle letter *c*</sup>

Dirac's bra came not much before 1939. In the preface to the third edition of his *Principles of Quantum Mechanics,* he says (boldfaced emphasis mine),

> The book has again been mostly rewritten to bring in various
> improvements. The chief of these is the use of the notation of bra and
> ket vectors, **which I have developed since 1939.**

Note that the second edition was published in 1935 (see [here](https://www.worldcat.org/title/principles-of-quantum-mechanics/oclc/610204336&referer=brief_results)).

(The third edition can be downloaded e.g. [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210812141526/https://digbib.ubka.uni-karlsruhe.de/volltexte/wasbleibt/57355817/57355817.pdf).)

The paper in which the bra-ket notation was introduced is *A new notation for quantum mechanics,* Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, Volume 35 , Issue 3 , July 1939 , pp. 416—418 [(link)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/new-notation-for-quantum-mechanics/4631DB9213D680D6332BA11799D76AFB).

***Bra* as short for *brassiere***

On the other hand, as user66974 pointed out in the comments, [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bra) says that *bra* as a shortening of *brassiere* appears 'by 1923'. The earliest appearance of it I was able to find on google books is in *Life* magazine from August 1932, p. 26:

> So, with a nest of pillows, began to bolster myself up against the
> walls of my boudoir clad in a **bra** and silk  shorts secretly purchased
> for Ned Wayburn, but deciding later against enlisting in his tap
> dancing class.

(It can be downloaded [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Life/69xGAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0).)

**Discussion**

If we can trust etymonline that *bra* as short for *brassiere* already existed by 1923, then the argument for the priority of this sense becomes essentially incontrovertible: 1923 was the year when Dirac only obtained his [undergraduate degree from the University of Bristol](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Collected_Works_of_P_A_M_Dirac_Volum/H-w8AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Dirac+graduated+1923&pg=PR17&printsec=frontcover). He then began graduate study at Cambridge University and only then started seriously thinking about quantum mechanics (in addition to thinking about general relativity). His Ph.D. dissertation was on quantum mechanics, and he [completed it in 1926](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Collected_Works_of_P_A_M_Dirac_Volum/H-w8AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Dirac+graduated+1923&pg=PR17&printsec=frontcover).

Another point to remember is that the Schrödinger equation didn't exist [until 1925—1926](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Historical_Development_of_Quantum_Th/-pL56OcVubgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Schrodinger+equation+1925&pg=PA445&printsec=frontcover); after that, one had to show that Heisenberg's and Schrödinger's formulations of quantum theory are equivalent and, more generally, one had to clarify the mathematical structure of quantum theory. This was a task to which many people contributed, but arguably the principal contributors were Dirac himself and, when it comes to full mathematical rigor, [von Neuman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann#Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics). (For further discussion, see Casado's [*A brief history of the mathematical equivalence
between the two quantum mechanics*](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507005604/https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/2735593.pdf).) Dirac's bra-ket notation would not make sense until the mathematical dust had somewhat settled, and that certainly could not predate the introduction of the Schrödinger equation.

**Conclusion**

So, *bra* as a short for *brassière* certainly existed by 1932 (and most likely even by 1923), while Dirac didn't develop his notation until not much before 1939 (and certainly after 1926).

Comment: And the winner for the 2022 "Most Discussion of Mathematics and Quantum Theory in an _English Language & Usage_ Answer" goes to...

Comment: With a side dish of Outstanding Lifetime Achievement Award, too!

Answer (score 8):

It appears that Dirac was in the know:

> Dirac, who invented this notation, called the symbol |..> a ket. The symbol <...|
> is a bra. It was said by my lecturers at Cambridge that when Dirac
> taught the subject, much of which was his own development, the only
> time he displayed any personal pride was when he told his little joke:
> a bra and a ket will be put together to form a braket, **<...|...>**  [Charles
> Francis; *Light after Dark II*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Light_after_Dark_II/UFAYDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dirac,%20who%20invented%20this%20notation,%20called%20the%20symbol&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover) p.109 (2016)

> One of Dirac's former students wrote about the lecture based on the
> book: 'Dirac was scrupulous in not underlining his own formidable
> contributions to quantum theory. However, one did gain the impression
> from a slight smile that played around his feature when he introduced
> bras and kets that this invention (and the harmless joke enshrined in
> the nomenclature) had given him great satisfaction.' [Sigmund Brandt;
> *The Harvest of a Century*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Harvest_of_a_Century/qcEUDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dirac%20braket%20joke&pg=PA160&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

---

It seems logical that *bra* as a shortening of *brassiere*, like *mayo* for *mayonnaise*, was in  conversational use before it began to appear in print (1940 for *mayo*), as reflected by these two early examples, one  in dialog, the other in an advertisement.

> They had unpacked their clothes, and Pauline was burrowing through a
> pile of lingerie looking for a brassiere . Downstairs everyone was
> dancing. "If I can't find that darn **bra'** I'll go without it,"
> threatened Pauline. [Eleanor Early; *Detour to Happiness*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Light_after_Dark_II/UFAYDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=dirac,%20who%20invented%20this%20notation,%20called%20the%20symbol&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover) (**1935**)

> Completely light and flexible, the two-way stretch all-elastic girdle
> with a **bra** attached, shaped like a pinwheel. [*Harper's Bazaar*,
> vol. 68, part 1](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Harper_s_Bazaar/uJMjAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=wear%20bra&dq=wear%20bra&printsec=frontcover) p.124 (**1934**)

Comment: This is a very interesting (and entertaining) answer. But, assuming only the information contained in this answer, a devil's advocate could claim that the following timeline is not excluded: 1. Dirac develops his notation (but only publishes it several years later); 2. *bra* becomes accepted as a short for *brassiere*; 3. Dirac learns of this development, and, *only* from then on, starts to snicker anytime he lectures about his bra-ket notation.

Comment: @linguisticturn That's possible--it occurred to me also. We have only these second-hand accounts so far. However, I would present before the jury an illustration showing a bra on the left and a blow up (size DD) of a braket on the right so they could draw their own conclusions.

Comment: Note that the "joke" doesn't actually invoke the brassiere at all: It is simply an explanation of the rather obvious pun.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic It does convey "aware of the humor."

Comment: The humor of "bra-ket is bracket, get it?", not necessarily "brassiere".